# ggplot2: Legend overlapping the plot area - is it possible to manually adjust legend position?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Lets say I have a dataset about carrot yield from different fields and different breeds:

```
carrots<-list(Yield=c(345,226,74,559,288,194),
          Field=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
          Breed=rep(c("Long","Short"),each=3))
carrots<-data.frame(carrots)
```

I want to plot a bar plot showing the yield for each field, coloured by breed:

```
ggplot(carrots,aes(y=Yield,x=Field,fill=Breed)) +
   geom_bar() +
   opts(legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.position = "top") +
   labs(fill="")
```

But the legend is always slightly overlapping the plot area:

[image: plot with slight legend overlap]
<sub>(source: [users.utu.fi](http://users.utu.fi/susjoh/Rplot.png))</sub>

I've tried manually adjusting the legend position to be outside the plot area, such as with

```
opts(legend.position=c(0.5,1.1)
```

but then the plot margins cut off the legend and I'm not sure how I can adjust them. Is there a more subtle solution to this problem?

Comment: +1 for a reproducible example, although you could remove the second step in your data preparation by calling `data.frame` instead of `list`.

Comment: Thanks Roman, any R advice is always appreciated :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my environment, the legend does not overlap the plot area at all, but anyway what is overlapping is the background of the legend, so you can remove it by:

```
ggplot(carrots,aes(y=Yield,x=Field,fill=Breed)) +
 geom_bar() +
 opts(legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.position = "top",
        legend.background = theme_blank()) + # this does hack
 labs(fill="")
```

Comment: Thank you kohske, this is the simple solution I needed. Strange that this is not universal - for information, I am using R 2.13.0 in Windows.